wget for packages.ros.org failing for https
When trying to run a simple wget for https://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz, I get the following error:
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|140.211.166.134|:443... connected.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name ‘packages.ros.org’.
To connect to packages.ros.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

I am attempting to use a library wrapper for package retrieval which enforces https, so while I can verify that the http variant of this works locally via wget, I am still stuck in my actual solution with the https variant.
After some digging, I can see this domain is a CNAME for https://ftp.osuosl.org/, which validates the name mismatch from here:
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=+https%3a%2f%2fpackages.ros.org%2f&run=toolpage#
Who can help fix this or is there a better forum to submit this issue?

Please use http endpoints for packages.ros.org
The https endpoints are not expected to work on our shared hosting and https doesn't work for common debian mirroring and catching mechanisms. All the indexes are signed individually via gpg with checksums for each package.
There are a lot of other threads about this for more generally Debian packaging. A found a few on  Reddit and Debian Forums for you reference.
